# Error SQL query Checking Available Room

Tags: php, sql

Everybody. I have a problem with my assignment about hotel booking online, So I have many table like:

```
tbRoom(RoomID,RoomName,...)
tbReservation(ResID,ResDate,....)
tbReservationDetail(ResID,RoomID,ArrvialDate,DepartureDate,....)
```

that my problem is Error when I write sql query Like this.

```
Select * from tbRoom as R where R.RoomID !=(select RD.RoomID from tbReservationDetail as RD where ArrivalDate < '2013-12-20' AND DepartureDate > '2013-12-17')
```

And it's Error :

```
unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE
```

for my purpose is: I want to get Room that available in between two date.

so, How I do?

Please help me, Thank for helping....

Comment: you forget to attach image in "![enter image description here][1]"

Comment: what is your version of phpmyadmin?

Comment: My PHP version is 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
Select * from tbRoom as R where R.RoomID NOT IN (select RD.RoomID from tbReservationDetail as RD where RD.ArrivalDate < '2013-12-20' AND RD.DepartureDate > '2013-12-17')
```

**Explanation**: First, you should use **NOT IN** instead of **!=**, because your child query is list, and, second, in your child query, you should use your table alias **RD** in your **WHERE** conditionals.

Comment: It still has error...

Comment: Please put here your current error

Comment: unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE

Comment: unknown table status: Create_time

Comment: Please share your full php script or a more global context of your problem

Comment: no I have test it in mysql and it have show the result but it show with error also...

Comment: It looks like a bug in phpMyAdmin (http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27912096). Have you tried in MySQL Client console? Do you have installed latest phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 0):

use `not in` in place of `!=` and not need naming table

```
Select * from tbRoom where RoomID not in (select RoomID from tbReservationDetail where ArrivalDate < '2013-12-20' AND DepartureDate > '2013-12-17')
```

Comment: I have to use it, and it also error like this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your phpadmin version to 3.4.0
[error in phpmyadmin](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2959746&group_id=23067&atid=377408)
Update the version , it will resolve your problem